# How to set color transparency to Google Geo Charts countries with no data?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am trying to make the background transparent for countries which don't have any data for tooltip but I can't find anything helpful in documentation.

Where do I need to set up the color attribute or is even possible to change the color ?

```
var options = {
   sizeAxis: {
      minValue: 0,
      maxSize: 100
   },
   colorAxis: {
      colors: ['#8a4cab', '#8a4cab']
   },
   legend: 'none',
   backgroundColor: 'transparent',
   keepAspectRatio: true,
   tooltip: {
      isHtml: true
   }
};
```

This is how is looking now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a76aQ.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use option --> `datalessRegionColor`

e.g.

```
datalessRegionColor: 'transparent'
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['geochart'],
  mapsApiKey: 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'value'],
    ['United States', 1],
    ['Canada', 1],
  ]);

  var options = {
    sizeAxis: {
      minValue: 0,
      maxSize: 100
    },
    colorAxis: {
      colors: ['#8a4cab', '#8a4cab']
    },
    legend: 'none',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    datalessRegionColor: 'transparent',
    keepAspectRatio: true,
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```css
#chart_div {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```